# How to load selected item from database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

So I have a default model set up for viewing my data, and a form for inputting the data. I want to know what the best practice is for retrieving the one item of selected data? it's for a MERN stack

Currently I am using window hash and adding the id onto the url and retrieving from database that way, I feel this is janky though and trying to add update functionality it seems like it might get confusing.

I've thought about adding a currentID to redux, but then I can see problems occurring when that is persisted and you go to create a recipe after viewing and end up editing instead of creating.

retrieving id from url

```
const recipeId = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  const recipe = useSelector((state) =>
    state.recipes.find((r) => r._id === recipeId)
  );
```

I get my recipes from mongo

```
export const recipeList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const recipes = await recipeSheet.find();
    res.status(200).json(recipes);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

and store to redux

```
export const getRecipes = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchRecipes();
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_ALL_RECIPES", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how large is your data. It'd better define a new GET path to retrieve a single record, like `BASE_URL/api/recipes/123` or you can add query acceptance for the current endpoint to find a specific id in DB and return it, like `BASE_URL/api/recipes?id=123`. The reason for that is besides the optimization (for large data sets), the record may change after you store all records to the redux store, and by the current solution, you show the old data to the user. Best practices tell us to choose the first way as your solution, the second way is usually for filtering the data. Then simply by sending the new URL by the user, trigger a new API call to the new endpoint and get the single record.